# Drupal Bootstrap Subtheme not styling the page

Tags: web, drupal, sass, drupal-7, themes

Working with Drupal 7 and Boostrap 3, and I have gone through the steps to create a subtheme, but I am still not getting what I thought I should be. When I enable and set the subtheme as the default, this is what my page looks like. I have watched others in videos following along with their steps, and their pages look like the bootstrap when you enable it. My team and I are super confused about all this. We are new to Drupal and Boostrap, and we have been thrown into the deep in on this project.  [image: screenshot of what i am getting] Now this is a screenshot of when I enable Boostrap as my default theme and what I was expecting the subtheme to look like. [image: what i was expecting] Here is a screenshot of my files.[image] Here is what I have in the .info file 
name = 'MyTheme'

```
description = My theme I am trying to get to work.
core = 7.x
base theme = bootstrap


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Regions
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

regions[navigation]     = 'Navigation'
regions[header]         = 'Top Bar'
regions[highlighted]    = 'Highlighted'
regions[help]           = 'Help'
regions[content]        = 'Content'
regions[sidebar_first]  = 'Primary'
regions[sidebar_second] = 'Secondary'
regions[footer]         = 'Footer'
regions[page_top]       = 'Page top'
regions[page_bottom]    = 'Page bottom'


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Stylesheets
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

stylesheets[all][] = css/style.css


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Scripts
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

scripts[] = 'bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/affix.js'
scripts[] = 'bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/alert.js'
scripts[] = 'bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/button.js'
scripts[] = 'bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/carousel.js'
scripts[] = 'bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/collapse.js'
scripts[] = 'bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/dropdown.js'
scripts[] = 'bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/modal.js'
scripts[] = 'bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tooltip.js'
scripts[] = 'bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/popover.js'
scripts[] = 'bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/scrollspy.js'
scripts[] = 'bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tab.js'
scripts[] = 'bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/transition.js'

; Disable the CDN provider so compiled source files can be used.
settings[bootstrap_cdn] = ''
```

My question would be, why is it not styling the page? Is there something I am missing? How am I supposed to get the sass to effect the page, when I can't even tell if it is working. I get it to where Drupal recognizes the subtheme and I can enable it, but that's about as far as I get.

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions:

1 - try to enable the base theme. So when you set MyTheme as the default theme pay attention that the bootstrap theme should be enabled.

2 - in the screenshot with your files I cannot see the css directory. Are you compiling the scss files into a css file? Notice that the .info file contains this line:

```
stylesheets[all][] = css/style.css
```

So all the style of your custom  module must be inside the css/style.css file of the MyTheme directory

Comment: Did that, fixed a few things, but now I get error messages on my page about improper CSS. I put in files that I was apparently missing and the bootstrap files that I got (untouched btw) from the site had some errors. Like the only modifications I have made was add a folder with the framework that the style.scss calls for and those files are returning errors when I compile them in Koala.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download [bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) theme and add this to your theme
   directory(sites/all/themes)
2. Enable your subtheme.
3. Try to clear the cache 
   (yoursite.com/admin/config/development/performance)
4. Click button: `Clear all caches`
5. Uncheck the two checkboxes under Bandwidth optimization

   - Aggregate and compress CSS files.
   - Aggregate JavaScript files.

Comment: Done that about a half dozen times. No joke, I even had another team member do the same and he gets the same.

Comment: Do you get any errors logged in Recent log messages?